# Liquid syntax : pass 5 date arguments

Tags: liquid

I'm using Liquid syntax for designers in cutsomer.io (mailing software).

I want to assign a variable a time format such as : $year$month$dayT$hours$minutes00Z ($ is just for legibility here)

e.g: 20150730T063000Z (2015/07/30 at 06:30)

here's my variable to get the first part (20150730):

```
{% assign my_date = 'now' | date: "%Y","%m","%d" %}
```

And I use it like :

```
{{ my_date }}
```

But I still get an error like "wrong number of arguments (5 for 2)"
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out, it was a syntax error, here's the correction :

```
date: "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:00Z"
```

Thanks :)